# Can't run anything as administrator in Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, administrator

I can't run any program as administrator on Windows 8 Enterprise, 64 bit.
I'm the only user and administrator. All programs that I've tried now, simplest notepad through gravest cmd, run smoothly as 'normal' none as admin.

I've learned from an earlier answer here that sfc/scannow can run without elevated cmd in safe mode, but it didn't help; it's result is in a log file, but now I was denied of access to open it. I also tried 'Automatic Repair' which too detected but couldn't repair some corrupt system files. I've also run MS Fixit and Tweaking Window Repair in vain; Reimage halted at 2% several times.

Furthermore, I've run Malwarebytes and Exterminate it! deleted what they found, but still the same.

Otherwise the laptop works perfect and I can't clearly define what I can or cannot do of what requires administrator privilege.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: "deleted what they found" What did they find?

Comment: Notepad doesn't not require elevated permissions to function. Infact none of the programs you listed require elevated permissions to get 100% functionality. **What do you mean you can't run any program as administrator exactly?**

Comment: So right clicking on a program and choose "Run as Administrator" doesn't work, or shows any error message?

Comment: Ramhound, every program may run as administrator for a reason; e.g. you can't start sfc/scannow in normal mode of Windows if cmd runs 'simply', can if it runs elevated; you can't edit your hosts file if notepad runs 'simply', can if elevated.

Comment: Darius, if I try to run anything as admin, I see the whirling blue ring that the system is busy for a second or even less, nothing else; no error message, no activity at all.

Comment: Jan Doggen, those were tracking cookies or similar mild stuff. I don't worry about them since I have Bitdefender Windows 8 Security that has a high reputation to stop anything really harmful. I just ran the other two for double check if something stirkes my eyes but nothing did.